# Regex for extracting the substring of a given type from a string

Tags: ruby, regex, string

Can someone help me in finding the regular expression for extracting the substring "CT23123" from the string "Andy Joe:CT23123" . I need a regex for extracting anything that is after ':' and is followed by two alphabets (can be in caps or small case) and 5 digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`/:([a-zA-Z]{2}\d{5})/`

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly.

Comment: The OP said the two letters must be followed by five digits, not be at least five digits: `"Andy Joe:CT23123999999"[/:([a-zA-Z]{2}\d{5})/] #=>  ":CT23123"`

Answer (score 1):

```
r = /
    (?<=:)    # match a colon in a positive lookbehind
    [A-Z]{2}  # match two letters
    \d{5}     # match 5 digits
    (?=\D|\z) # match a non-digit or the end of the string in a positive lookahead
    /xi       # extended/free-spacing mode (x) and case-indifferent (i)

"Andy Joe :CT23123"[r] #=> "CT23123" 
"Andy Joe:CT23123a"[r] #=> "CT23123" 
"Andy Joe:CT231234"[r] #=> nil
```

or:

```
r = /
    :               # match a colon
    ([A-Z]{2}\d{5}) # match two letters followed by 5 digits in capture group 1
    (?:\D|\z)       # match a non-digit or the end of the string in a non-capture group
    /xi             # extended/free-spacing mode (x) and case-indifferent (i)

"Andy Joe :CT23123"[r,1] #=> "CT23123" 
"Andy Joe:CT23123a"[r,1] #=> "CT23123" 
"Andy Joe:CT231234"[r,1] #=> nil
```

Answer (score 0):

Another version using the case-insensitive option:

```
/:([a-z]{2}\d{5})/i
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a regular expression for this, its a bit overkill. Try the string method `split`.

`"Andy Joe:CT23123".split(":")` will return:

```
=> [
    [0] "Andy Joe",
    [1] "CT23123"
]
```

So you can use `"Andy Joe:CT23123".split(":")[1]` to get:

```
=> "CT23123"
```

Or, if you're worried about `split` being slower for larger N, use [partition](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-partition) as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26349350/1521117).

`"Andy Joe:CT23123".partition(":")`

```
=> [
    [0] "Andy Joe",
    [1] ":",
    [2] "CT23123"
]
```

Comment: Suppose the string were: "Lizzie:2, Andy Joe:CT23123, Rufus:999".

Comment: I'd split on the comma first, then on semi colons. If the arrangement is truly unpredictable, then use a regular expression.

Comment: The commas are irrelevant. Suppose it were "Lizzie:2, Andy Joe:CT23123 and Rufus:999"? The point is that we don't know from the question if there must be exactly one colon in the string. You could make that assumption, of course, but it should be stated.

Comment: I'd probably do something like `t.split(" ").map{|s| s.partition(":")}` and dump the sub arrays with empty strings if N is small because I think it's easier to maintain(personally). For large N I'd use a regular expression.